# Unable to attach metadata to Google Cloud Storage using NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am referring the following code to upload a file into Google Cloud Storage 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-getting-started/blob/master/3-binary-data/lib/images.js#L48

I was able to upload successfully, Now i am trying to add metadata to file so i have modified the code as below

```
  const stream = file.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
      contentType: req.file.mimetype,
      foo: 'bar'
    }
  });
```

But the foo=bar metadata is not getting attached to the file in Google Cloud Storage

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to attach metadata to file, then you need to keep that data under metadata. Change your code to the following

```
const stream = file.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
      contentType: req.file.mimetype,
      metadata: {
        foo: 'bar'
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a million mate! Having "metadata" nested under "metadata", such a gotcha!

Comment: I tried to find a link to the docs to add to this thread but I could not. Upvoting for poor souls like myself in the future.